GetOpenFilename setting displayed columns
I am using Application.GetOpenFilename to have a user navigate to a directory with a larger amount of directories.  My company has set up various attribute / detail columns to help navigate / filter this information.  The default detail columns that come up when the dialogue window opens do not shows these columns.
I found this question which seems a little dated and I was wondering if perhaps something has changed since it was asked
How can i use GetOpenFilename and turn on the columns for "Author", "Tile" and turn off the Column for "Type", "Size", "Modified"
My Code:
Private Sub BrowseBtn1_Click()

Dim Result As Variant
Dim OldDrive As String, OldDir As String, DefaultPath As String

    OldDir = CurDir
    OldDrive = Left(CurDir, 1)
    DefaultPath = "U:\"
    
    ChDrive Left(DefaultPath, 1)
    ChDir DefaultPath
    
    Result = Application.GetOpenFilename("Forecast File (*Forecast*.xlsm), *forecast*.xlsm")
    
    ChDrive OldDrive
    ChDir OldDir
    
    If Result <> False Then
        FileTextBox.text = Result
    End If

End Sub

